# WPF ComboBox binding not always working (property gets assigned from an async call)

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, mvvm

I have a dialog which has its DataContext assigned in the code-behind. When a button (somewhere in the UX) is clicked, an asynchronous command is executed. In that command, the dialog is initialized and then gets opened.

The problem now is, that sometimes the ComboBox is empty. Does anyone see, how this could go wrong?

I can print the values from the asynchronous database-access before opening the dialog, and the values are always there.

There are other fields in the dialog, which are bound to the ActiveUser object. That object is not being set from data originating from an async call. Those values are always present, unlike the ComboBox ItemsSource. So I assume, it has something to do with the async call.

Creation and opening of the dialog in a command:

```
EditUser = AsyncCommand.Create(async (choosenUser) =>
{
    // create a dialog, which has its DataContext assigned in the constructor in the code-behind
    EditUserDialogView dialog = new EditUserDialogView();
    // assign a property (non-async)
    ((EditUserDialogViewModel)dialog.DataContext).ActiveUser = (DbUser)choosenUser;
    // get the list of UserTypes async
    List<UserType> userTypeList = await DataAccessService.GetUserTypesAsync();

    // Debug output -> usertypes are always printed correctly, so are available at this point
    foreach (UserType ut in userTypeList)
    {
        Log.Info("UT: "+ ut.UserTypeName);
    }

    // assign UserTypes to property bound to combobox ItemsSource
    ((EditUserDialogViewModel)dialog.DataContext).UserTypeComboBoxList = userTypeList;


    // open the dialog
    if (dialog.ShowDialog() == true)
    {

    }
    else
    {

    }
});
```

Binding in dialog:

```
 <ComboBox IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
       ItemsSource="{Binding UserTypeComboBoxList, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
       DisplayMemberPath="UserTypeName"/>
```

The AsyncCommand is implemented as suggested here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn630647.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

(The only difference is, that the parameter for the lambda is the CommandParameter (here choosenUser), not a CancellationToken.)

Here is the property definition in the ViewModel for the dialog:

```
 public List<UserType> UserTypeComboBoxList { get; set;}
```

I figured out, how I can fix this behavior. When I change the property to raise a NotifyPropertyChanged event, it will always show the ComboBox correctly, containing the values.

```
public List<UserType> UserTypeComboBoxList
{
    get { return userTypeComboBoxList; }
    set
    {
        userTypeComboBoxList = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(UserTypeComboBoxList));
    }
}
```

As all values should be initialized by the time I open the dialog, I do not see why raising this event changes anything.

Comment: Perhaps it's some kind of race condition. When you define the property wrong and depend on luck for it to be initialized before the binding looks at it, sometimes your luck holds, sometimes not. When you define it correctly, luck isn't an issue: If the property is initialized after the binding is created, that's fine. The binding is notified of the change and it updates. Order of execution doesn't matter, which simplifies things.

Comment: )ther points: Viewmodels shouldn't "know" about controls. It seems like nitpicking, but you write better code if you think of the VM as a platonic abstraction. I'd call the property `UserTypes`. Secondly, I'd use `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` rather than `List<T>`. Items added to the list won't be shown in the UI, and you don't need or want to add any anyway, so build that fact into the class by using a read only collection type. Let the compiler keep track of that stuff. You could use `ObservableCollection<T>`, but OC plays very poorly with threads.

Comment: Absolutely agree about the "knowing" of the controls. I actually ended up with this construct, because a dialog can't be closed through a binding. So I initialize the ViewModel in the dialogs constructor and set a lambda on the ViewModel which will set the dialogs DialogResult property. The correct way would be to create a DependencyProperty.

Comment: Why get the viewmodel involved in closing it? The OK button can have a click handler, the Cancel button gets `IsCancel="True"`. `ShowDialog()` returns true or false, and the viewmodel doesn't know or care about the dialog closing. It just maintains whatever state it gets from initialization or values it was given by bindings in the dialog view. I feel like we're talking past each other a  bit.

Comment: Because the Save button will do some more work after being pressed. So if something goes wrong, it won't close the dialog and show a message.

Comment: That sounds like view logic to me, not viewmodel. But yeah I now I see what you're getting at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the race condition. Since, the database call (to fill comboBox) is invoked `asynchronously` so if before the dialog initializes, asynchronous call is completed then the `comboBox` is displayed properly; If not, then you see that you are assigning the new object to property `UserTypeComboBoxList` (without `NotifyingPropertyChanged`) which would change the reference of property and in this case, `XAML` binding loose tracks of it property reference until not notify explicitly which is being done by the later property definition.

So the later code of Property definition is correct. The other way of achieving the same behavior is using following (if the bound data can be changed during the program execution):

1. Use the [ObservableCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx) which provides the notification
   when object is added/deleted into collection
2. Instead of initializing a new object for property
   `UserTypeComboBoxList` in your action, initialize at Constructor,
       and `Clears` & `Add` the updated values everytime.

Comment: An ObservableCollection would have to be created on the UI thread, adds and removes would have to be invoked, etc. It's a can of worms. Seems to me that this is really a `ReadOnlyCollection<UserType>` -- it's never going to change after it's initialized, and if changes won't be reflected in the UI even if made, the collection type should reflect that.

Comment: Very true @EdPlunkett, `ObservableColletion`  should only be used if the bound data is going to change. If the data is initialized only once then `ReadOnlyCollection` is a better option.

Comment: How can it have a race condition here (there must be one, agreed)? As far as I understand, the execution will stop once we reach the await, until the async call returns. So how can the dialog be opened before the async call returns? (btw. the property can be read-only, as suggested in the comment).

Comment: @ptair I wouldn't agree there *must* be a race condition. What you described sounded not inconsistent with one, though.

Comment: @EdPlunkett True, it just feels like one. I currently can't see, how I could have one here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be, that once I create the dialog and InitializeComponent() is called, C# starts to assemble the final View class (asynchronously) and initializes the bindings. So my assignments of the properties of the ViewModel will either by luck be the initial assignment, because it was not already bound, and sometimes it will be an update of the already bound empty initial value.

This can be prevented by initializing the ViewModel before assigning it to the View.

Comment: I've meant the same. However, I'have used the word load instead of control initialize --- `InitialzeComponent` :). Silly me.

Comment: Not silly, just not so precisely explained. The 'load' instead of 'initialize' was exactly the reason why it wasn't clear. I assumed you mean opening the dialog with 'load' (as you can see from my question under your answer). But given that change, I see that you got it right.